# Есть ли события Enter и Leave для двух прямоугольников

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

Два прямоугольника на *Canvas*`е, один во время анимации проходит над вторым.

Вопрос, есть ли библиотеки или встроенные события, которые помогут изменить цвет в момент пересечения?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Вариант 1:** [Geometry.FillContainsWithDetail](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms607451.aspx)

Допустим, прямоугольники движутся по `path1` и `path2`. Тогда:

```
var intersectionDetail = path1.Data.FillContainsWithDetail(path2.Data);

if (intersectionDetail != IntersectionDetail.NotCalculated && intersectionDetail != IntersectionDetail.Empty)
{
    //ваш код
}
```

**Вариант 2:** [Rect.IntersectsWith](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.rect.intersectswith.aspx)

Пусть есть два прямоугольника - `rect1` и `rect2`. Тогда:

```
if (rect1.IntersectsWith(rect2))
{
   //ваш код
}
```